# How can I use one var or let from a view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I made a popup view controller but now I'm trying to pass the data from the popup to the view controller via prepare function. Let's take a look.

```
// this is from the pop up view controller

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let toBeMoved :ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    toBeMoved.enterVC()
    amountEntered.text = "\(runningNumber1)"
} 

// and I added a func in my main VC but I can't get the var in the VC
// totalCash is a label to be changed when the amount is entered from the
// pop up vc

func enterVC () {
    totalCash.text = "\(amountEntered)"
}
```

I added `enterVC` to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Make sure you are not trying to assign an IBOutlet a value in prepareForSegue. Since the view isn't loaded yet it will crash, you need to create a variable in your mainVC and then assign that String to the label in viewDidLoad for example. Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Turns out I needed to put a guard let in order to make this work also added IBAction in the original view controller like so:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

@IBAction func didUnwindSegue (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        guard let realVC = sender.source as? ViewController else {
            return
        }

    }


}

class TestVC : UIViewController {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let realVC = segue.destination as? ViewController else {
                return
        }
        realVC.totalCash.text = runningNumber1
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see:

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let toBeMoved :ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        toBeMoved.amountEntered = runningNumber1
        toBeMoved.enterVC()
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {   
    var amountEntered: Int = 0
    func enterVC () {
        totalCash.text = "\(amountEntered)"
    }
}
```

---

or try this also.

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let toBeMoved :ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        toBeMoved.enterVC(amountEntered: runningNumber1)
    }

}


class ViewController: UIViewController {      
    func enterVC (amountEntered: Int) {
        totalCash.text = "\(amountEntered)"
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but what do I pass in as the sender?? is it not optional?

Comment: Anything you can pass into sender but here you may not need to pass any value, if you can access `runningNumber1` directly in this method. (You need to pass nil or `runningNumber1`).

Comment: How do I call that override function into play when I Hit the button? I have it with no errors I just need to add it to my IBAction button

Comment: Was able to solve the problem with guard let and IBaction. Thanks for your fast response I do appreciate it